# Angular service return Invalid data "undefined" for parameter id in url requested

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a service that is called in a component but returns error 400 bad request with message

> Invalid data "undefined" for parameter id

Knowing that the method `getProduct` in api works perfectly.

**Service.ts**

```js
getProduct(ID: number): Observable<any> {
  // console.log('ID', ID)
  return this.http.get(environment.api+'/products/' + JSON.stringify(ID)) as Observable<Product[]>;
}
```

**component.ts**

```js
searchIdAction(id: number){
  return this.venteService.getProduct(id).subscribe(
    product => {
      // console.log('product', product);
      this.product = product;
    },
  )
}
```

**component.html**

```js
<clr-input-container *ngIf="options == 1">
  <label>Recherche:</label>
  <input clrInput placeholder="recherche  par id ..." type="number"  (keyup.enter)="searchIdAction(modelProduct.id)"/>
  <!-- name="name" [(ngModel)]="modelProduct.id"   -->
</clr-input-container>
```

Need your help please. Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no need to stringify the id bcs it is a number instead of json, Try to remove that and pass the id directly and try again.

Comment: why did you stringify id ?

Comment: thanks for your quick answers. same as taking off stringify, the error undefined id persist

Comment: In searchIdAction method print id before passing it for an API and from where `modelProduct` object coming from?

Comment: my problem is that the input value is not readed as id passed in parameter. i didn't know how can i fixed this

Comment: Can you please check whether that you are correctly defined the API. Check this part  'environment.api+'/products/' + JSON.stringify(ID)'. You may be added an additional '/' before 'products'.

Comment: this is my method in api

Comment: @get('/products/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Product model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': Product}}},
      },
    },
  })
  async findById(@param.path.number('id') id: number): Promise<Product> {
    return await this.productRepository.findById(id);
  }

Comment: #sammaani95                                   <input clrInput placeholder="recherche  par id ..."  #myInput name="myInput" [(ngModel)]="modelProduct.id" tyep="number" (keyup.enter)="searchIdAction(myInput.value)" />
it read the id but it is malformed it return when i input 2 : Invalid data "\"2\"" for parameter id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's resolved. I hope that can help others

```
<input name="idInput" [(ngModel)]="idInput" type="text" (keyup)="searchProduct(idInput)" clrInput placeholder="recherche  par nom ..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I'd say that you lack some model binding on your input, and consequently, your id is always undefined. There is no way for Angular to know that you want to put your input's value into `modelProduct.id`.

You should either use the `ngModel` commented below your input, or directly access the input value if you don't need to store this value:

```
<input #myInput clrInput placeholder="recherche  par id ..." type="number"  (keyup.enter)="searchIdAction(myInput.value)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Carm, you are right the problem in the input. It read the value inputed but he treats it as undefined message: "Invalid data "\"1\"" for parameter id

Comment: this is my input edited                                   <input clrInput placeholder="recherche  par id ..."  #myInput name="myInput" tyep="number" (keyup.enter)="searchIdAction(myInput.value)" [(ngModel)]="modelProduct.id"/>